# WebSphere App Server native_stderr.log is getting rapidly updated and growing too big in size

Tags: java-native-interface, websphere, logging

I am running an application in WebSphere Portal Server 6.1 and WAS 7. In the native_stderr.log , I am getting the following error message :

```
<JNI GetStringCritical: buffer=0x000000004D810988>

<JNI ReleaseStringCritical: buffer=000000004D810988>
```

These messages fill up the log rapidly and the size of the log increases rapidly and grows up to 1 GB in about 5 minutes.

This does not seem to be related to our deployed application since even when the application is not in use the logs keep getting generated.

Can anyone please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages are from -verbose:jni.  Turn that off to remove the messages.  From the admin console:

Servers > (Server Types) > WebSphere application servers > server1 > (Java and Process Management) > Process Definition > (Additional Properties) > Java Virtual Machine

There is an option "Verbose JNI".  Alternatively, you have -verbose:jni specified manually in the "Generic JVM Arguments" argument.

Answer (score 0):

You got to provide additional info besides this for folks to help.

What is the JNI Stuff that you have in your application?

Notice the call here - GetStringCritical() would likely be blocking GC on the JVM.

Try and turn off the JNI component of the application and see how your servers behave

Manglu

Comment: Hi, thanks. But My application does not use JNI. This is probably something that WebSphere is doing internally. This is where I am puzzled too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn this off in the config files:

(You will have to modify this path to your own setup)

```
../WAS-7.0/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/config/cells/localhostNode01Cell/nodes/localhostNode01/servers/server1/server.xml
```

Look for the  tag, you will see it has there:

```
verboseModeClass="false" 
verboseModeGarbageCollection="false" 
verboseModeJNI="false"
```

etc